# Wordwrap label in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uilabel, word-wrap

I searched for this problem but the solutions i found didn't work for me. I have a textfield. When user writes something to textfield, it writes it to the label. This label is on an imageview, when label reaches the imageview limits. I want that label wordwrap and go to second line. Now it is like this but doesn't work.

```
    @IBAction func textchanged(_ sender: UITextField) { 
    if(mylabel.frame.minX < imageview.frame.minX && mylabel.frame.maxX > imageview.frame.maxX)
    {
    mylabel.frame = CGRect(x: mylabel.frame.origin.x, y: mylabel.frame.origin.y, width: mylabel.frame.width, height: mylabel.frame.height * 2 )
    mylabel.numberOfLines = 2
    mylabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    mylabel.sizeToFit()
    }
    mylabel.numberOfLines = lines
    mylabel.text = textfield.text
    mylabel.sizeToFit()
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Try this :  label.numberOfLines = 0

Answer (score 2):

Remove height constraint from label in Xib (If you have set constraint for height)

and Use this

```
label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
label.numberOfLines = 0
label.text = textfield.text
```

Comment: It doesn't have a height constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating label in the delegate function

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool
```

Also see that uitextfield delegate is properly set

Comment: It gives this error: ` Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[instayaz2.ViewController textFieldShouldEndEditing:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fed1640a7d0'`

Comment: Delegate is like this;  textfield.delegate = self
        textfield.addTarget(self, action: #selector(UITextFieldDelegate.textFieldShouldEndEditing(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.editingChanged)
        panRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.draggedView(_:)))

Comment: try textfield.delegate = self